# Including Qt tools in a dll project with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, qwidget, qtgui

I am creating a dll project using Visual Studio 2010.

Can QWidgets like `QLabel`, `QPushButton`and `QImage`, etc be inserted in a `dll` project? Can I import Qt functions into a dll project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can. 
just dont forget to careate a QApplication instance.
and run in separate thread `qApp()->exec()`